# Django Rest: Hashing used in set_password() function of BaseUserManager

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can I know the hashing algorithm used in set_password() of BaseUserManager
Early on, I assumed that it must be creating a same output(encrypted password) like make_password(). But both gives different outputs

For example,

```
pbkdf2_sha256$120000$fpYd7FD1Cf3Z$sHRDYkxU6wST9i17AeVZeDPMGjwSpV4U1+8bxTC7B9U=
```

this is hashed using set_password() method in my app(which is the encrypted form of the password, `'password'`

then in the python shell,

```
>>>from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
>>>make_password('password')
```

gives an output

```
'pbkdf2_sha256$120000$PCjS8f7J2zU8$7pj4Xp5R1h935z9U3UyRlcprJpQRgUID+I9UQp+q1w4='
```

and I run the make_password('password') command once again,interestingly, this time also it gave a different output

```
'pbkdf2_sha256$120000$Jyhjh4luFw4F$wMKnv4BuNVw0NFpKgQjJNoyC6CuMqeXCo1neTEQ6S58='
```

So, what I want is I want to add a change password feature in my app., So I want my user to type his current password before changing it. As it is hashed using set_password(), I cannot check it directly., and I think the only possible way is to hash the inputed password and then check it with the original one.
Can anybody help me in solving it?

Comment: But if you're checking against an existing user's password, why can't you use `user.check_password()`?

Comment: actually I don't heard about this. Because I'm new to Django and Django Rest

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you please share a little more details

Comment: I'm not sure what more you need. To check an existing user's password, use `user.check_password()`.

Comment: The reason the password is different everytime you run `make_password` is because the password is salted, the format of the password is actually `<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: @A.J.Parr Thank you. it was a very useful information