# Django Rest Create hashed password manually

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create hashed passwords manually that should be exactly same when we hash password using set_password() function.

I tried make_password(), but when I use it, it gives different outputs for same input like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210269/django-rest-hashing-used-in-set-password-function-of-baseusermanager)

How can I solve it?

Comment: its not possible to get same hash everytime using make_password() so has specified in the link you shared you may use check_password()

Comment: so isn't there any way to implement this?

Comment: Of course there is - the question is why? :)

Comment: There is case of update password in my app. so I need to use `set_password()` or some other methods equal to it. otherwise the new password will get updated as it is. What I need is I need to call a `patch()` request from front end to update my password